# 'Stick' image to right side of the page

Tags: html, css, image, position

My last question wasn't very clear, I'll give it another try.

On my Tumblr blog (http://anti-standard.tumblr.com) you can see an image (the image says 'ANTI STANDARD') wich is stuck to the left side of the page. However, I want the image to be stuck to the right side of the page. How can I do this? I have the following CSS code:

```
.image-container1 {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    right:0;
    clear:both;
}

.image-container2 {
    background:url('http://avare.nl/tumblr/as.png') no-repeat fixed;
    background-size:55px 500px;
    height:500px;
    width:55px;
}
```

And the following HTML code right below the 'body' tag:

```
<div class="image-container1">
    <div class="image-container2">
    </div>    
</div>
```

I hope you guys can help me out with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:right` to `.image-container2` and remove fixed from the background

```
.image-container2 {
    background:url('http://avare.nl/tumblr/as.png') no-repeat;
    background-size:55px 500px;
    height:500px;
    width:55px;    float:right;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SYshT/1/)**

Or in easy way do like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-container1">lorem ...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{height:100%}
.image-container1 {
    width:100%;
    background:url('http://avare.nl/tumblr/as.png') no-repeat right top;
    background-size:55px 500px;
    height:100%
}
```

​**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SYshT/3/)**